# Create and Run a simple java Program in intelliJ without all the advanced features?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, ide, code-completion

I am just learning java and have come to a point where coding in 'vi' is killing my hands
I'm considering an IDE like 'intelliJ' with code Completion but don't want to use all that project tree , packages etc and be caught up in its complexity, i'll learn how to use an IDE later ,
Can someone tell me how to just create and run , just a .java file along with codee completiona and debuggin , so that i dont need to save with 'wq' , compile and open vi.filename.java each time, this is why i want an IDE , to make this easier, so please guide me on how to do just this in IntelliJ or suggest some other IDE with good codeCompletion, 
I know this question is subjective but i;m  askinng it since i just had a hard time typing a simple GUI quiz Application

Comment: So, what is your question? IntelliJ has [quick start guide](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Quick+Start) that will tell you how to get started using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create new Java project (File/New Project/Java), select *Create project from template* and choose *Command line app*. This creates a project containing a class with empty main method, which you can run by hitting <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> or debug using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd>.

This whole process takes only like 20 seconds.

And as far as the directory structure complexity goes, you have just one directory that you need to be concerned about - src/. You can keep all your classes in the default package if you want and therefore all your code will be in src/ without any subdirectories for packages.

I don't think it gets any easier than this.

Answer (score 0):

Most IDEs make you create a project to start coding, so I usually have one project called 'test' for whenever I want to try a bit of code.  Make one java class file that has a main class and use <kbd>F5</kbd> or find the run option in the menu.

Comment: Yeah but they insert their own package names and directory structure and stuff , I want the simplicity of a text editor like vi and powerful code completion of intelli J like Ide , any way ?

Comment: Java requires packages, so if you don't provide it with package names, the IDE will simplify your workload by making packages for you.  I find it quite helpful.